# Is it possible the nested use of !reference in gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: reference, gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

**rules.yml**

```
.rules:
  default:
    - .gitlab-ci.yml
    - Makefile
    - VERSION

  a_pybuild_deps:
    - !reference [.rules, default]
    - foo/a/**

  b_pybuild_deps:
    - !reference [.rules, default]
    - foo/b/**
```

It works if I am simply referring to `default`:

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
include:
  - local: "./rules.yml"
   
a_pybuild:
  ...
  stage: py_build
  script:
    ...
  only:
    changes: !reference [.rules, default]
```

But I want to do the following:

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
include:
  - local: "./rules.yml"
   
a_pybuild:
  ...
  stage: py_build
  script:
    ...
  only:
    changes: !reference [.rules, a_pybuild_deps]

b_pybuild:
  ...
  stage: py_build
  script:
    ...
  only:
    changes: !reference [.rules, b_pybuild_deps]
```

Like this I will get a lint error: `jobs:a_pybuild:only changes should be an array of string`
I understand the problem, but is there any proper way to apply this?

Answer (score 3):

As of GitLab 14.8, [you can use nested `!reference`s](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#nest-reference-tags-in-script-before_script-and-after_script) up to 10 levels deep, but only for `script:`, `before_script:` and `after_script:`.

Nesting of `!reference` is not allowed in other keys, like `only:` which is why you get this error.

In versions of GitLab prior to 14.8, nested `!reference`s are prohibited entirely.

In your situation, you would simply have to manually duplicate your default rules into `a_pybuild_deps`  and `b_pybuild_deps` or omit the default rules from those keys entirely and `!reference` both the default and respective pybuild keys in the job.

This is probably the most flexible and DRY way to do it is to use `rules:` instead of `only:` and arrange your rules like so:

```yaml
# rules.yml
.rules:
  default:
    changes:
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
      - Makefile
      - VERSION

  a_pybuild_deps:
    changes:
      - foo/a/**

  b_pybuild_deps:
    changes:
      - foo/b/**
```

```yaml
#.gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - local: "./rules.yml"


a_pybuild:
  script: '...'
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules, default]
    - !reference [.rules, a_pybuild_deps]

b_pybuild:
  script: '...'
  rules:
     - !reference [.rules, default]
     - !reference [.rules, b_pybuild_deps]
```

Comment: I tried to apply your solution but it is triggering 2 pipelines on push.
I tried to solve it via the description here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#two-pipelines-when-pushing-to-a-branch, but If I apply a `workflow:rules` then my rules for the job will not work anymore. I mean in the example `a_pybuild` job should only run when one of the followings (`.gitlab-ci.yml`, `Makefile`, `VERSION`, `foo/a/**`) has been changed. But If I make a change in another directory, for example in `foo/b/**` then the job will be triggered. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am now having the same problem.
As [sytech mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72957604/5449104), according to GitLab docs, nested references cannot be used in `changes`.

My solution is to use [YAML anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors) instead of the internal reference. It works.
Pay attention that unlike reference, the anchor must be defined in the same file it is used.